# Converting WEbPage to Pdf file using PDFBOX

Tags: spring-mvc, pdfbox

How can I convert webpage into pdf file using PDFBox, if you guys can share some good documents to go through would be helpful..

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: PDFBox doesn't support converting HTML to PDF.

Comment: So What PDFBOx does?

Comment: PDFBox can render, manipulate and create PDF files.

Comment: I want to create a pdf , and the contents should look exactly like the web page . Is it possible ?

Comment: Not automatically. With PDFBox you'd have to do every little step yourself. There may be software products that do this, but not PDFBox.

Comment: Could you please guide me to do that.. I mean do you have any sample code or documents.

Comment: I can't guide you, but I can tell you to have a look at the examples in the source code download. E.g. EmbeddedFonts.java, ImageToPDF.java, AddImageToPDF.java, ShowColorBoxes.java.